# Why is WHERE ""="" true?

Tags: sql, select, sql-injection

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question but I'm reading about SQL injection and one of the mentioned instances of the such state that a SQL command such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
WHERE Name ="" or ""="" 
AND Pass ="" or ""=""
```

would be valid and return all records of the table users. I understand the logic behind doing something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
WHERE UserId = 105 or 1=1
```

but I can't seem to figure out why `""=""` would be a true statement. I'm quite new to SQL in general and I've searched for an answer but most examples of SQL injection only mention the 1=1 example.

Comment: blank = blank should be true right?  Why would it not be the case?

Comment: `""=""` is invalid SQL because double quotes are for identifiers, not for string literals. So `""=""` would compare two columns - but with an "empty name".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True in ANSI SQL but not true in all implementations of SQL servers.

Answer (score 4):

> I can't seem to figure out why `""=""` would be a true statement.

An empty string is equal to another empty string.  Not sure where the confusion is.

> I've searched for an answer but most examples of SQL injection only mention the 1=1 example.

It's just another way of dealing with the appended quotes.  The original code is probably something like

```
string sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ="' + username + '" AND Pass ="' + password + '"'
```

so passing in the value `'" or ""="'` would result in the string you see.

Another one you see sometimes is passing in the value `'" OR 1=1 --'` which results in the SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ="" OR 1=1 --" AND Pass ="doesn't matter"
```

Which effectively removes the remaining SQL since the compiler treats it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The empty string equals the empty string, doesn't it?

Comment: lol, i feel like an idiot. I didn't see it that way now that you mention it. I guess it really was a dumb question.

Comment: BTW: You grouped the WHERE clause incorrectly. And has higher binding then or. So actually it's evaluated as Name ="" or (""="" AND Pass ="") or ""=""

Answer (score 1):

`""=""` compares an empty string to another empty string, so the result is true, exactly like if you were comparing `'1'='1'` or `'FooBar'='FooBar'`.

Comment: `""` is not a String in SQL - it's an (empty) identifier.

Answer (score 0):

`'' = ''` is true for the same reason as `1 = 1` is true. You can compare strings to strings in SQL.

Think of it this way: when you compare two names, like this: `'ihor' = 'ihor'` they are naturally equal, right? Now just pretend that the name is... empty :) That's it. An empty string is a value on its own, so it is ok to compare it against another empty string.

In contrast to an empty string (which is a value), `NULL` is the absence of the value. And since you cannot compare absence to absence both `NULL = NULL` and `NULL <> NULL` are false in SQL.